# Can I use any-measurement words before “of”?

Tags: prepositions

used after words or phrases expressing amount, number, or a particular unit:

1. a kilo of apples
2. loads of food
3. hundreds of people

From The Cambridge Dictionary

Can I say like 3 degrees (temperature) of apple or 3cm (extent) of apple? Or should it be related to either number or amount?

Comment: Hello.  I notice that you are asking "apple questions".  These are often about hypothetical situations that have been created to illustrate particular points of grammar.  But what do you actually want to communicate.  What context do you actually want to say "3cm of apple"?

Comment: @James K I just made it for “of” I ate 3cm long part of 5cm long apple.

Comment: “I ate 3cm long part of 5cm long apple” is not something I would expect to hear from any native speaker “**I ate a small piece** (because 3cm is pretty small) **of** apple” makes sense and has meaning. "I had 3 cm of apple” is acceptable although still odd.  You can say **the apple was 3ºC** but not “3ºC of apple”. We can speak of **the peel/colour/juice/taste/texture of an apple** but not the number of degrees, thickness, depth of colour etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**3 cm of apple** is properly constructed and would make perfect sense in a context where apples had to be sliced to specific dimensions—to be dried and sold in packages, for example.

In most contexts, **3 degrees of apple** would not make sense. **Apples** are not parsed by degrees. **Temperature** is parsed by a degrees. In the proper context, you could say **Three degrees of temperature.**

However, it would have to be a special context. The default meaning of **degrees** in English refers to temperature. Thus, you would only use the word **temperature** to distinguish it from another sort of degree that was already present in the context.

I can imagine a very strange situation in which the following conversation makes sense:

> Bob: Please slice the apple into discs. Then slice each disc into 3-degree sections.
>
> Sally: Right. Three degrees of apple, for a total of 120 sections. They will be very small
>
> Bob. Exactly. And please do so at 10 degrees.
>
> Sally: I thought you said three degrees!
>
> Bob: I mean 10 degrees of temperature. We must keep the apples cold to avoid spoiling.

But really, this conversation would never occur.

Answer (score 1):

3cm of apple is grammatically fine, but almost completely meaningless.

If you have some apple (the uncountable pulp, and not the countable fruit) and you are drawing lines with this pulp, you could theoretically measure the amount of apple by the length of the line.

But that never happens.  It is not a realistic situation for communication.

3cm of apple does not mean "an apple with a diameter of 3cm"

And 3 degrees of apple does not mean "an apple with a temperature of 3 degrees".